# Service fabric stateless services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-service-fabric

I have an azure service fabric application, and I have multiple microservices. Each microservice is a stateless service with its own database.

Question:

If I would have more than one instances of the microservice then will each instance have it's own database or will all instances shared the same database?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. If you are just making a connection to a database for CRUD actions then no. What database are we talking about and what is the interaction between the database and the service?

Comment: I have an azure service fabric application, and I have more than one microservices , each microservice is a reliable stateless service having its own database, if I will more than one instances from one of the microservices , each of these instances will have its own database instances or all instances will keep connecting to one shared databse instances

Comment: Well, normally databases do not get created when they are connected to. What database are you using, SQL Server?

Comment: yes I am using SQL server

Comment: Assuming that the services do not create database and all instances of the same stateless service use the same connection string then obviously they will all connect to the single database specified in the connection string. So,  all instances will keep connecting to one shared databse instance

Comment: @PeterBons Thank you very much for your help